# How do I set up a firewall/iptables using rc.firewall?

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables

I am new to Ubuntu and am having a bit of trouble getting my firewall set up for my Network Security class. We are set up with 3 virtual machines - a Gateway, a Server, and a Client. We are supposed to create a file rc.firewall to create iptable packet filtering. Unfortunately, we only have a few requirements - no steps or any real hints on implementation.

I have create an rc.firewall using some code my teacher provied. I can look up how to handle most of the requirements within the file, but I'm a bit confused on how to get the file to do anything.

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Created rc.firewall in /etc/rc2.d/rc.firewall
2. Made the file executable by running the command chmod +x /etc/rc2.d/rc.firewall
3. Edited the rc.local file to run on startup (I think?) and added the line sh /etc/rc2.d/rc.firewall

And... I'm stuck. Assume that the rc.firewall file is correct. Is there a way to start the firewall without restarting? Restarting the virtual machines always screws something up. I'm looking for as much information on how to use th rc.firewall file as possible. The few "tutorials" I have found are vague. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal.

Run it:

```
sudo -i
mv /etc/rc2.d/rc.firewall /etc/init.d/
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/rc.firewall
update-rc.d rc.firewall defaults
```